# Why I cannot use the Linq Where clause in a method of a public abstract class?

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, where-clause

I have the following construct and I cannot use the `Where` clause as part of a linq query and I wonder why:

```
public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(List<int> testCollection)
    {
        var result = testCollection.Where(.......).Select(.....);

    }
}
```

Intellisense does not recognize the `Where` clause and I also get a compile error. Is that related to me trying to use it within an abstract class? I use .Net 4.5 and I can construct Linq queries in regular classes.

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` directive at the top of the file? There's no other apparent reason why it wouldn't be recognized...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor, stupid me. You are of course right, though strangely neither VS suggested that a using reference was missing nor Telerik's JustCode. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you got `using System.Linq;` at the top of the C# file? :)

Comment: Stupid me, really missed that. You are of course right, though strangely neither VS suggested that a using reference was missing nor Telerik's JustCode, which is the first thing I checked. Thanks